# How to divide a word into syllables, given a simplified, standardized phonetic alphabet?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have a [glyph system](https://github.com/tunebond/tone) used to write phonetically, so I wanted to ask a question somewhat related to that (you don't need to learn about that for this question though). Given a phonetic glyph system, where each glyph represents one "sound" or phoneme, I'm wondering how you could parse a "word" (sound sequence without spaces) into syllables, or at least count the syllables since the syllable boundaries are not at the letters but perhaps in between letters.

So for this question I will pose a simplified alphabet, where each letter/glyph means one exact sound. Assume each glyph means only one sound, the standard sound you learned as a child (assuming English fluency), and assume these are the only sounds:

- consonants: m n b d g p t k h s f v z r l (r is rolling r like in spanish)
- vowels: i a u

Now, given "words" using these sounds, how can you figure out how many syllables there are? You can have chains of consonants (like `ks` or `tr` or more than two perhaps), and chains of vowels (like `au` or `ui`, etc.).

Here is what I have:

```js
const words = `
glars:1
glarsana:3
golman:2
garmanipona:5
trakropsa:3
bunarmki:3
bap:1
bauni:2
balinta:3
`.trim()
  .split(/\n+/)
  .map(line => {
    const [word, count] = line.split(':')
    return {
      word,
      count: parseInt(count, 10)
    }
  })

words.forEach(log)

function log({ word, count }) {
  console.log(word)
  console.log(`  expected: ${count}`)
  console.log(`  computed: ${getSyllableCount(word)}`)
}

function getSyllableCount(word) {
  let initial = word.split(/[iau]/g).length
  if (word.match(/[iau]$/)) {
    initial--
  }
  return initial
}
```

This isn't quite right (and also, is it roughly this easy, I'm curious now if this will work on English if it is spelled phonetically). How can it be fixed to match the expected count beside the word in the JavaScript word list? It's a bit mind bending trying to figure out how to count the syllables precisely like this.

Comment: Just look at the result of `word.split(/[iau]/g)` for each word and it should become clear what the problem is

Comment: You have an "o" in one of the words. You'll also have to define exactly when two consecutive vowels are a diphthong and when not, like in "cooperation".

Answer (score 1):

You need a clear definition of "syllable" to write an algorithm. That definition will vary by language.  It is also often inconsistent WITHIN a language.  It may also vary by speaker.  The same word over time can migrate from 2 syllables, to a diphthong, to a single sound.  As an example the various words in English that end with ough (though, through, bough, etc) are believed to have started as 2 syllable words that migrated to one syllable by different paths, winding up as different words.

In short, there is no algorithm because the problem is not well-defined.

As for your writing system, I would suggest having some good conversations with qualified linguists before continuing.  Just at a glance I can see a number of problems.  Here is a short list.

1. I may have missed it, but I cannot see that you've accounted for voice tones, which are important in languages like Chinese.  If you do account for them, how do you account for not needing them in English?  Or should you insist on including them when they carry a semantic meaning?  For example we pronounce "What?" and "What!" with different voice tones.  Anglophones see that as one word pronounced in two ways.  To Chinese speakers they sound like completely different words.
2. How do you handle allophones?  Anglophones are unlikely to be aware that the "t" in "top" and "stop" are different sounds, but Thai speakers cannot fail to notice it.  Allophones often switch from one regional dialect to another in English, do we write these as different words?
3. How do you handle pronunciation shifts?  Older speakers of English, and some dialects, will pronounce "wine" and "whine" as different words.  Most people growing up today pronounce them as the same word.  People near a transition often do are not aware of which choice of pronunciation they actually use.  For example Randall Monroe (of XKCD fame) [didn't realize](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dF9_2Bc9RsY&t=585s) that he pronounced "cot" and "caught" differently until someone else told him that he did.
4. What about sound differences that you cannot hear?  Take the English "n" sound.  It is partway between the Russian "н" and "нь".  (The "ь" is a soft sign that modifies the preceding letter.)  But the distinction between those sounds is one that most anglophones cannot recognize.  I, personally, got to where I could correctly identify them 10 times out of 10, but still felt like I was just randomly guessing.  If you've never tried to learn Russian, you almost certainly would be just guessing.
5. How many sounds was that, really?  The Russian "нет" is transliterated into English as "nyet".  The number of letters is the number of sounds each hears.  How so?  The "е" puts an implicit soft sign on the preceding "н", and the anglophone will hear a diphthong in the transition between them.  But what the anglophone hears as a fast "y" sound is actually a part of "нь" that is always there, and the Russian listener registers a single sound.

So far we have that in a universal phonetic alphabet, one English word should turn into several, you have to write different letters in places that you don't realize are different, different people saying the same word needs to be written differently, people often do not know which way they pronounce the words they use, you would need to write down distinctions that you can't even hear, and someone will have to write down a different number of sounds than they think that they heard.

This is not to slight your attempt.  You've put a lot of effort into it.  But trying to create a universal phonetic alphabet is a [wicked problem](https://www.interaction-design.org/literature/topics/wicked-problems).